# Mock frameworks returns class with different name and type

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I'm trying to create a mock to satisfy a typehint with this code (Mockery):

```
return \Mockery::mock('\Contracts\Helpers\iFileSystemWrapper');
```

or this (PHPUnit):

```
return $this->getMock('\Contracts\Helpers\iFileSystemWrapper');
```

But the mock returned is called `Mockery\Mock Object` or `Mock_iFileSystemWrapper_a5f91049`. How am I supposed to type check this when it isn't an instance of what I need at all with either framework?

Why exactly is the mock framework trying to load the real class? If I wanted the real class I would include the real class.

This problem has slowed me down so many times when writing tests I'm about to just toss type hinting out the window and check class names instead, or simply use production objects as mocks are a pain to use.

Comment: Show result of `var_dump($mock instanceof \Contracts\Helpers\iFileSystemWrapper);` where `$mock` is what this code returns

Comment: I had this problem with PHPUnit too, it was seriously driving me crazy. Sometimes mocks would be interfaces and other times not.

Answer (score 4):

I just experimented with an existing test of my own, and by changing the interface namespace name from one that exists to one that doesn't exist, I got exactly the same as what you describe (using phpunit). My mock object had the class name `Mock_ViewInterface_c755461e`.  When I change it back to the correct interface name, it works fine.

Therefore I would say that either:

1. You are trying to use an interface name that doesn't exist (e.g. a typo or missing namespace component).
2. Your library code isn't being loaded for some reason, e.g. autoloading is not setup correctly in your unit test bootstrap.

Answer (score -2):

You need use a special function to check base class.
Somthing like this:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('MyClass');
$this->assertInstanceOf('MyClass', $mock);
```

Comment: This only tests that the mock object is an instance of the class or interface you already gave, which is really just testing the test framework :-)  However if you instead use a regular `if` statement and `instanceof` operator, then a good IDE will stop showing you its "invalid parameter type" warning.